# 18.04. Booting only works after reset. ACPI Error

Tags: boot, acpi

I ve got the following issue. 
When starting my laptop (an old Toshiba) it makes it over the grub loader but then often freezes with a graphical error with the ubuntu background colour or I just get a black screen. 
When reseting the laptop with the button I see a terminal saying:

```
[ 0.048760] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [integer] (ptrval) (20170831/exresop-103)
[ 0.048804] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE. while resolving operands for
[ 0.048848] ACPI ERror: Method parse/execution failed \PR.CPU0._PDFC, AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20170831/psparse-550)
/dev/sda6: revocering journal
/dev/sda6: clean, etc. etc. etc....
```

Also i noticed that the BIOS is already quite old (2012). Could that be a thing? I am afraid to just update it.

Now that I ve been using this laptop for a couple of weeks I notice that the graphics and audio are stuttering occasionally. Eg when watching a movie it sometimes stops for a millisecond. I remember that I also had that problem 5 years ago when using that laptop the first time. Might this issue be related to the first one?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Is this a new install and always broken or an old install that just recently broke after an update?

Comment: I havent had the problem i think before I installed 18.04. However I cant remember. I myself havent used this laptop for a while and just use it more often now because my personal one has some WIFI issued I am trying to solve at the same time.